# How to use hamachi to transfer files over a private network

Tags: networking, vpn, hamachi

please help, How to use hamachi to transfer files over a private network

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little vague but I will try to give it a shot.

First both computers must be on the same hamatchi private network. The target computer (and possably your computer too, i am not sure) needs to have windows file sharing enabled in the hamatchi settings and on the computer itself. then navigate to `\\5.x.x.x\` and fill in the x's with the ip address of the target computer and that will open up the windows share.